# Wso2 esb, exception using UsernameToken security

Tags: java, security, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want make secure the access to a rest service using the Wso2 ESB 4.8.1.
My service is compose by an http get request that call the proxy defined on the ESB.
The proxy defined the my http get service and protect using UsernameToken security.
This is the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="prova3"
       transports="https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:8080/download/"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="ScenarioID">scenario1</parameter>
   <enableSec/>
   <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/prova3/services/prova3/policies/UTOverTransport"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

When I try to invoke the service it the esb throw the following exceptions :

```
[2015-01-16 09:33:17,028] ERROR - Axis2SynapseEnvironment Error while building message
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,24]
Message: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.detach(OMElementImpl.java:700)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.setParent(OMNodeImpl.java:105)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:212)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPEnvelope(TransportUtils.java:161)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.buildMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:593)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:319)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,24]
Message: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 25 more
[2015-01-16 09:33:17,035] ERROR - SequenceMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,24]
Message: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.detach(OMElementImpl.java:700)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.setParent(OMNodeImpl.java:105)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:212)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPEnvelope(TransportUtils.java:161)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:493)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,24]
Message: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 23 more
[2015-01-16 09:33:17,039] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while building message
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:110)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:493)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while building message
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator.handleException(AbstractMediator.java:313)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,24]
Message: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.detach(OMElementImpl.java:700)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.setParent(OMNodeImpl.java:105)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:212)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPEnvelope(TransportUtils.java:161)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,24]
Message: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 23 more
```

What is the cause of the error?